# Is this transformation linear?

Tags: linear-transformations

The input is $v=(v_1,v_2)$

$T(v)=v_1v_2$

Is this linear transformation?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: What is $T(2v)$? And $2T(v)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Take:

$$v = (1,0)$$

and

$$u = (0,1)$$

Then check whether:

$$T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$$